# Can I disable the Facebook login button on certain conditions?

Tags: javascript, facebook

I want to allow the user to click the 'fb:login-button' (which I'm using for registration as well) only if they've entered valid input in a text box on my page.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

One simple way would be to position a div directly on top of the button. If the div is transparent, the user will see the button but not be able to click on it; if the div is the color of the background, it will make the button "hidden"; or you could even have a semi-opaque div to give the button a "dimmed" effect.  In each case just move the div or set display:none to return the button to normal operation.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the [registration plugin](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/) and do validation of your custom field yourself?